# Eclipse took overnight to close and is still trying to close

Tags: eclipse

I tried closing Eclipse because there was a bug in the Java code, and then I successfully closed it. "Success" may not be what was expected. Now, the closing message shows up... I thought it would finally close after I went to sleep, but NO! It's still on and I don't know what happend to Eclipse. Here's the message:

[image: Eclipse Error]

Does anyone know what's wrong with Eclipse? I have no clue why this is happening, and I can't even open eclipse anymore, but that's a different problem.

Thanks for anyone who could help.

Comment: Eclipse is being Eclipse. Kill it with fire. :)

Comment: Eclipse use to be my favorite Java editor xD :P

Comment: It's been like that for almost 24 hours now...